# Make UITextField tab when textFieldShouldReturn executes

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Currently I am trying to make my UITextField tab to the next textField when the user presses enter. I believe I need to do it inside my textFieldShouldReturn method, but how?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

I have also already made each textField a delegate by putting these in my viewDidLoad

```
UserFirstName.delegate = self;
UserLastName.delegate = self;
UserEmail.delegate = self;
UserUser.delegate = self;
UserPassword.delegate = self;
```

Comment: have you set delegate of textfield?

Comment: Yes I have. definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , and change textfield accourding to your requirements.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];  
  [yournexttextfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags for that.

```
UserFirstName.tag = 1;
UserLastName.tag = 2;
UserEmail.tag = 3;
UserUser.tag = 4;
UserPassword.tag = 5;
```

And in your UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextField* nextTextField = (UITextField *)[textField.superview viewWithTag:(textField.tag + 1)];
    if (nextTextField) {
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, and I'm sure tagging will come in. But @Aklesh Rathaur has the simplest method